# How to $filter where condition is matched against an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

after $lookup i will get a join named lastViewed like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"

    lastViewed: [
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1705"),
           "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
           "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
           "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2017-06-19T09:39:07.374Z")
        },
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1764"),
           "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
           "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab162"),
          "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-11T09:39:07.374Z")
        }
      ]
}
```

I want to use $filter and then $project values ,
my query is below where the userId is getting from params

```
$project: { "viewedDetails": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$lastViewed",
                            "as": "lastViewed",
                            "cond": { $and: [{ "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }, { "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.groupId", '$_id'] }] }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I got the exact output as below for userId 58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b

```
{
  "_id" : "5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"

    viewedDetails: [
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1705"),
           "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
           "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
           "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2017-06-19T09:39:07.374Z")
        }
      ]
}
```

Now i changed my schema into and got $lookup result as

```
{
  "_id" : "5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"

    lastViewed: [
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1705"),
           "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
           "members":[
                  {
                    "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab162"),
                    "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-11T09:39:07.374Z")
                  }
                  {
                    "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
                    "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2016-05-19T09:39:07.374Z")
                  }
              ]               
        }
      ]
}
```

then my filter for array of objects is not working , my query is

```
 $project: { "viewedDetails": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$lastViewed",
                            "as": "lastViewed",
                            "cond": { $and: [{ "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }, 
                                             { "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.members.groupId", '$_id'] }] }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

How can i get this without using $unwind, then using $project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to `$unwind` purely for comparison, since there are various operators which can determine a logical result by comparing to a list. You really only need change the `cond` on the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here;

Filtering the "members" requires wrapping with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to reflect the change though:

For MongoDB 3.4 you can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/in/):

```
"viewedDetails": {
  "$map": {
    "input": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$lastViewed",
        "as": "lastViewed",
        "cond": { 
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }, 
            { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$lastViewed.members.groupId" ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "as": "v",
    "in": {
      "_id": "$$v._id",
      "userId": "$$v.userId",
      "members": { 
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$$v.members",
          "as": "m",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$m.groupId", "$_id" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which compares the value against each of the values in the array returned by `"$$lastViewed.members.groupId"` and returns `true` or `false` depending on if it is a match.

If you cannot use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) then only the initial `$filter` need change to one of the following:

Eariler than tat use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)

```
   "cond": { 
     "$and": [
       { "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }, 
       { "$setIsSubset": [ ["$_id"], "$$lastViewed.members.groupId" ] }
     ]
   }
```

or even [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

```
   "cond": { 
     "$and": [
       { "$eq": ["$$lastViewed.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }, 
       { "$gt": [ 
         { "$size": { 
           "$setIntersection": [
             ["$_id"], 
             "$$lastViewed.members.groupId"
           ]
         }},
         0
       ] }
     ]
   }
```

Where the "intersection" resulting in a "set" that has "more than" `0` elements means that the value was present within the same referenced array.

Note that in those forms we make the `"$_id"` value an array as `["$_id"]` since the "set comparison" is between "sets" and not an individual field.

---

### Proof

This is the document you provided with corrections to syntax:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
    "lastViewed" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1705"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
            "members" : [ 
                {
                    "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab162"),
                    "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2017-05-11T09:39:07.374Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
                    "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2016-05-19T09:39:07.374Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the pipeline stage being run:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "viewedDetails": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$lastViewed",
            "as": "lastViewed",
            "cond": { 
              "$and": [
                { "$eq": [ "$$lastViewed.userId", ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b") ] }, 
                { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$lastViewed.members.groupId" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "v",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$v._id",
          "userId": "$$v.userId",
          "members": { 
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$$v.members",
              "as": "m",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$m.groupId", "$_id" ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

And here is the output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
    "viewedDetails" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("595218a7d346d27fb0bc1705"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("58c796d4344b9da4dfbe027b"),
            "members" : [ 
                {
                    "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"),
                    "lastViewedTime" : ISODate("2016-05-19T09:39:07.374Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Neil but the query returns both the elements in members array, i need only members array with ` "groupId" : ObjectId("5955ea4fd8099718330ab191"), ` and its lastviewed time. appreciating response

Comment: @arunraj414 Okay you want to filter `"members"` inside the array as well? That was not clear in your question. We need to wrap in a `$map` to reflect this. Give me a moment.

Comment: @arunraj414 There, now the `"members"` array will only return the matching array item. The earlier condition on the first `$filter` would exclude the whole array if nothing was matched in here, so we don't need to check for empty results of the `$filter` that "re-shapes".

Comment: @arunraj414 You keep coming back to the site but there is no feedback. What part of the solution here do you not understand? This provides a replacement for the existing `$project` stage that will actually filter the arrays as requested. If you don't understand or disagree then please explain.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks a lot. i will try this out by the day itself and let you know. gone busy with some other stuffs

Comment: Hi Neil, checked with your answer, but not getting the output, its not projecting any values

Comment: @arunraj414 Works perfectly for me. What are you changing? Just replace your `$project` with the listing here.

Comment: @arunraj414 I've included the corrected data from what you posted, the query being run and the output. All you need to is copy and paste them yourself as proof of output. Then work out what you are doing wrong, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Neil, just done-> {$project : { "your code" } }, but it returns nothing, i have updated the question for my expecting answer, gone through your query and got it (excellent one). am checking on it, can you please look into once more

Comment: @arunraj414 Dude. Look up above. I have included the copy and paste output of the thing working exactly as you asked. Big heading called Proof

Comment: sure Neil, i will check it and let you know, thanks in advance