# How to get the information if a product is already added to a wishlist / cart in product catalogue made with express.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my product catalog, how can I assign the information if a product is already in my wishlist/cart? I would like to disable the “add to wishlist“ for the product that’s already in the wishlist/cart.

I use express.js with mongoose.
Currently, I store the wishlist in the user object with a reference to the product.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    wishlist: {
        items: [
            {
                ProductId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

I query the product catalog with `Product.find({})` and render the result with pug.

Comment: You have the user's wishlist loaded before quering for products?

Comment: do you mean that it is assigned to an array in the callback function before `Product.find({})`?

Comment: Yes, can you get the array of the ProductIds to do a nin on your Product.find()?

Comment: I did it like this. 
In the controller I create an array: `var wishlistItems = req.user.wishlist.items.map(a => a.productId)` before `Product.find({}) `
In the view I check if the product exists in the wishlist via: `if !JSON.stringify(wishlistItems).includes(JSON.stringify(product._id))`
If it’s true, I render „Add Product to wishlist“ else „The Product is still on the wishlist“. I had to convert the objects to strings because the comparison between objects results false. Is this the kind of solution you had in mind?

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally misunderstood what you were trying to do. My comments were more for filtering out products like in @Colin Daniel's answer. I would do some console.log(ging) in your view of your wishListItems. It should be an array which you can do an indexOf(product._id) on. If it's an object with other properties other than the product Ids it could give you unexpected results in your conditional.

Comment: I try to make it clearer next time.
Anyway, your answer triggered the solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(**Updated**)
Try something like this:

controllers/Store.js

```
const Users = require("../models/Users")
const Products = require("../models/Products")

router.post("/addToWishlist", async(req, res) =>{
  try{

    //query for specified user
    const user = await Users.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });

    //query for all products except for what's on the list
    let stuff = await Products.find(
          {_id:{ $not: {$in:[...user.wishlist.items]}}
      });
      res.status(200).json({ // or res.send/res.render
        data: stuff
      })
    });
  }
  catch(err){

    res.status(500).json({ // or res.send/res.render
      message: err.message
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution will filter out the products which are on the wishlist, right? 
Every Product should remain in the catalog. Just the wishlist button has to change the state.

Comment: Kindof, personally, I haven't used $filter or any type of aggregation yet so really my answer is wrong but someone else solved this problem before. [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868505/how-to-filter-where-condition-is-matched-against-an-array). Also, collection queries won't alter your collection unless you use findAndModify, findAndDelete etc.[Here] (https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) are the docs for $filter.

Comment: I updated my answer to be simpler than using aggregation try this instead  @davidinteract